# Users are not register in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Hello I am new to asterisk doing first time configuration and setup. I have configured the sip.conf and added two entries.

7001 and 7002.

I downloaded the zoiper on the same system where i setup the asterisk now 7001 user has been registered in zoiper but in network there is another system on which I installed the zoiper and its display registering..wait for 10 min but still it did not register.

Please check my screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This site is for programming questions *only*, system administration is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

There are about 999 possible reasons this isn't working, but you really haven't given us enough information to help you out.
Please post extract of your SIP.CONF file showing the two sip peers you created.
Also, please post a diagram of your network topology showing where the "not working" extension is.
Lastly, post any error messages that show on the Asterisk CLI as well as on the Zoiper info.

I will -strongly- encourage you to take a couple of hours and go read http://the-asterisk-book.com/1.6/index.html right now.  If you are brand new to Asterisk, you really do need to take the time to learn the basics and understand a standard configuration.

Comment: Two PC are on the LAN. Other PC in which SIP is not registering in the zoiper and when i am trying to register from the other pc then there was not error message on the Asterisk CLI.

Comment: Sip.conf [7001]
host=dynamic
context=default
nat=yes
secret=ajay

[7002]
host=dynamic
context=default
nat=yes
secret=chetan

Comment: what are the two IP addresses of the two PCs; give the IP and the extension number, please?

Comment: Okay. I will post the extension file so that it will help me and good for you as well to look this issue.